# Laplacian and Fourier Transform in a differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplacian

I am dealing with the following equation
\begin{equation}
\lambda\nabla^2f(r)=f(r)
\end{equation}
where $f(r)$ is a function only of the radius $r$ in spherical coordinates and $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian operator. Using that $f(r)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$, the Laplacian of $f(r)$ can be then written as
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2f(r)=\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\dfrac{2}{r}\dfrac{df}{dr} \equiv f''(r)+\dfrac{2}{r}f'(r)
\end{equation}
Putting this in the first equation and giving it to Mathematica or WolframAlpha, it says that the solution is
\begin{equation}
f(r)=C_1\dfrac{\sqrt{\lambda}\;e^{r/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{r}+C_2 \dfrac{e^{-r/\sqrt{\lambda}}}{r}
\end{equation}
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary integration constants, fixed by the boundary conditions (not interested in them now). However, If I take the Fourier Transform on both sides,
\begin{equation}
f(r)=\int \dfrac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\hat f(k)e^{ikr}
\end{equation}
the only information this gives is $-k^2=\lambda$, since $\hat f(k)$ appears in both side of the equation. How can the solution be derived via Fourier Transform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your permission I will rewrite the initial equation in the form
$$\nabla^2f(r)=m^2f(r)$$

First, from the Laplace equation in spheric coordinates
$$\Delta f(r)=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\Bigl(r^2\frac{d}{dr}f(r)\Bigr)=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\Bigl(r^2\frac{d}{dr}(rf(r)\frac{1}{r})\Bigr)=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\Bigl(r\frac{d}{dr}(rf(r))-rf(r)\Bigr)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}(rf(r))=m^2f(r)\Rightarrow rf(r)=C_1e^{-mr}+C_2e^{mr}$$

$f(r)$ is defined for all $r$, except for $r=0$ and $r=\infty$, where the function has singularities.

In many cases a Green function $G(\vec r,\vec\rho)$ of the equation is required. In our case the equation for Green function (spherically symmetric over $r$) has a form
$$\Bigl(-\Delta_r+m^2\Bigr)G(\vec r,\vec\rho)=\delta(\vec r-\vec\rho)$$
$G(\vec r,\vec\rho)$ allows to find a general solution of the equation $\Bigl(-\Delta_r+m^2\Bigr)f(\vec r)=g(\vec r)$ with the right side $g(\vec r)$ in the form $f(\vec r)=\int_{R^3}G(\vec r, \vec\rho) g(\vec \rho)d^3\vec\rho$

At $\rho=0$ we get the initial equation $\Bigl(-\Delta_r+m^2\Bigr)f(\vec r)=\delta(\vec r)$ with the only difference: delta-function is in the RHS. But due to the fact that $\delta(\vec r)$ iz zero for all $r\neq0$ the solution of this equation will coincide with the solution of the initial equation for all $r\neq0$.

Let's find $G(\vec r, \vec\rho)$, and then we will put $\vec\rho=0$.

Applying FT to the both sides of the equation $\Bigl(-\Delta_r+m^2\Bigr)G(\vec r,\vec\rho)=\delta(\vec r-\vec\rho)$ we get $$\hat G(\vec k,\vec\rho)=\frac{e^{-i(\vec\rho,\vec k)}}{m^2+k^2}$$

Applying inverse FT

$$G(\vec r,\vec\rho)=\int \dfrac{d^3\vec k}{(2\pi)^3}\hat G(\vec k,\vec\rho)e^{i(\vec k,\vec r)}=\int \dfrac{d^3\vec k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{i(\vec r-\vec\rho,\vec k)}}{m^2+k^2}$$ $$=2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} \dfrac{\sin\phi \,d\phi\, k^2dk}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{i|\vec r-\vec\rho|k\cos\phi}}{(k+im)(k-im)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin\phi\,d\phi\, k^2dk}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{i|\vec r-\vec\rho|k\cos\phi}}{(k+im)(k-im)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^2i|\vec r-\vec\rho|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i|\vec r-\vec\rho|k}-e^{-i|\vec r-\vec\rho|k}}{(k+im)(k-im)}k\,dk$$

To integrate we close the contour in the upper half plane for the first term and in the lower - for the second one (to get vanishing integrals along these half-circles at $R\to\infty$) and evaluate residuals at $k=\pm im$.

Finally we get

$$G(\vec r,\vec\rho)=\frac{2\pi i}{2(2\pi)^2i|\vec r-\vec\rho|}\frac{e^{-m|\vec r-\vec\rho}\,\, 2im}{2im}=\frac{e^{-m|\vec r-\vec\rho|}}{4\pi|\vec r-\vec\rho|}$$

At $\rho=0$ we have $$f(r)=\frac{e^{-mr}}{4\pi r}$$

It is not surprising that we got only finite (at $r\to\infty$) part of the solution: FT implies that smooth functions which we transform are finite.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks, my doubt is clear now. Just one thing, as you say at the end, we only obtain the finite part of the solution after aplying FT. Even though, the general solution of the problem would be the one I posted with the raising exponential too, right? Thanks again!

Comment: @NambuGotto Yes, raising function is also a solution; the problem is that I don't know how to get it by means of FT (if it is possible at all - FT deals with finite functions...)

Comment: Very good, thanks a lot. Yes, I think that your point is correct and since FT deals with smooth and finite functions the other contribution can't be recovered. However I was interested in how to obtain information from the FT, so your answer is perfect.