# How would you prove this Laplacian/Dirac Delta relation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dirac-delta, laplacian

How would you prove this

$$(\nabla^2 + k^2)\left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right) = -4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})$$

using the fact that $\nabla^2(\frac{1}{r}) = -4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})$?

I'm getting tripped up with how to apply the $(\nabla^2+k^2)$ term and going around in circles.

Comment: Did you start by computing $\nabla(e^{ikr}/r)$ using the product rule?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080253/laplacian-and-fourier-transform-in-a-differential-equation/4080469#4080469

Comment: Presumably $kr$ in the exponential should be $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

In distribution, we apply the product rule for the Laplacian, $\nabla^2(fg )=f\nabla^2 (g)+2\nabla (f)\cdot \nabla (g)+g\nabla^2(f)$, with $f=\frac1r$ and $g=e^{ikr}$ to find

$$\nabla^2\left(\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\right)=\underbrace{\frac1r \nabla^2\left(e^{ikr}\right)+2\nabla \left(\frac1r\right)\cdot \nabla (e^{ikr})}_{\text{Now, expand this.}}+\underbrace{e^{ikr}\nabla \left(\frac1r\right)}_{=-4\pi \delta3(\vec r)}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I'm still ending up with an extra term of $\frac{-2ike^{ikr}}{r^2}$, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @tesscbear You're welcome.  My pleasure.  That term is offset by a term from $\frac 1r \nabla^2 (e^{ikr})$

Comment: I calculated $\nabla^2 e^{ikr}$ wrong initially. Thanks so much! I'm unable to vote as I'm so new.